# How to read ansible variable value from bash using adhoc commands?

Tags: bash, ansible

I want to read the value of `ansible_distribution_major_version` into a `bash` variable by calling `ansible` using adhoc commands.

The closest I got was the command below but this still got me some extra output that may not be very easy to parse or even worse, that could change in the future.

```
ansible localhost -m setup -a "filter=ansible_distribution" -o
localhost | SUCCESS => {"ansible_facts": {"ansible_distribution": "MacOSX"}, "changed": false}
```

How can I do this in a nice and clean way?

Just to be clear, in the end I would like to endup with `MacOSX` value inside a bash variable.

Comment: Is using Ansible a requirement? There might be better ways to figure out the local OS than using an Ansible task.

Comment: Have you ever heard of [`uname`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uname)?

Comment: I will not go into details but yes, using Ansible is a MUST in this case. Yep, I know lots of alternative ways to get similar info without it.

Answer (score 0):

If ansible is a requirement then I'm not aware of any out of the box solution. Could look into callback plugins (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/plugins/callback.html), maybe developing one that does exactly what you need (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/dev_guide/developing_plugins.html#callback-plugins).

Could also change the default callback to something else which is readily available (i.e. json) and process the standard output. Can configure in your `ansible.cfg` ...

```
stdout_callback = json
bin_ansible_callbacks = True
```

... or using environment variables: `export ANSIBLE_LOAD_CALLBACK_PLUGINS=true` and `export ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=json`.

Then process the json with i.e. python (for sure there are probably better examples than this):

```
var=$(ansible localhost -m setup -a "filter=ansible_distribution_*" |python -c "import sys, json; print json.load(sys.stdin)['plays'][0]['tasks'][0]['hosts']['localhost']['ansible_facts']['ansible_distribution_major_version']") # var=18 (Ubuntu 18.04)
```